# InvalidRouteException on MVC3 application with multiple areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception, authentication, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have a MVC3 web application with one default area and one admin area. Both have their won home pages after logging in. After successfully logging in to the application if i try to access the admin area i am getting InvalidRouteException.

Scenario is like that i login to the application successfully. When i try to access the admin area using

`http://localhost/admin`

i get following exception.

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> {controller}/{action}/{id} { controller: 'admin'; action: 'LogOn' } 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: LoginSystem.Web.Exceptions.InvalidRouteException:
>   {controller}/{action}/{id} { controller: 'admin'; action: 'LogOn' }

However if i log-out and then use URL like

```
http://localhost/admin
```

it takes me to the login page successfully.

Please suggest.

Below is my RegisterArea function for the consumer area.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Consumer_default",
                "Consumer/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "MyPortal.Web.Areas.Consumer.Controllers" }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
            "Admin", // Route name
            "Admin/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new[] { "MyPortal.Web.Controllers" }// Parameter defaults
        );
       }
```

**More Information - Update 1**
After registering "Admin" Route i am able to move to the Logon page. 
My application has 2 areas Client and ADmin(this is default one.) Both areas are authenticated.
Now the scenario is that i logged in to client module. While i am logged in, i did

```
http://localhost/admin
```

and reached the Logon page. But the issue is that now the url donot contain the Return URL. What should i do so that it contains returnurl.

In normal scenario when we are not logged in the Logon page opens with return url added to its url.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is there a redirect in the LogOn action if already logged on?

Comment: No such thing. Adding more, the above mentioned url is not even hitting the action method logon.

Comment: Seems like if logged in, the url is resolved some other way and if not logged in, the url is resolved some other way and is somehow mapped to the action method logon. I am new to mvc so i dont know how the urls are mapped to the action methods. and How the application knows that it is logged in. ?

Comment: Is there a redirect __away__ from `localhost/admin` when not logged on?

Answer (score 0):

Reads like you haven't configured global.asax.cs & AccountController.cs correctly. I had a similar problem the other day and took me a little to remember I'm doing customizations of my routing. I have an admin section with a localhost address much like yours. Here's what I did:

In your global.asax.cs file, add the following:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Admin", // Route name
            "Admin/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The above describes a route with a name of admin. The second line, says to look for a url that looks like:

```
http://localhost/admin/
```

With an appropriate "home" action.

Your admin controller should start with:

```
 //
    // GET: /Admin/
    [Authorize]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Tutorial.ToList());
    }
```

Then when dealing with you authorization, you'll want to adjust the Account controller on the [Http] post of LogOn, specifically the RedirectToAction to:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
```

The other area that needs adjustment is [Http] post:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Admin");
            }
```

Course, I'm assuming you're talking about the default security/membership provider.

HTH.

Comment: I have added the new route described by you. But still having the same error.

Comment: @user3056239 W/out a complete code example of what you have, I'm walking in the dark.

Comment: How can i provide you more details? Please let me know.

Comment: @user3056239 I realized yesterday that you probably didn't need to add that custom map path in global.asax.cs. Just provide some code examples of what you have.